# AppleScript for Mail Attachments not working in Mojave beta 10

Tags: applescript, macos-mojave

The following script works fine in High Sierra but fails to attach files to the Mail message in Mojave. The message title, content and recipient are set correctly, but not the attachment. Any ideas?

```
set theAttachment to (choose file with prompt "Select file for attachment...")

tell application "Mail"

    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"File Attachment Test", content:"Some test content" & linefeed & linefeed}

    tell theMessage
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:"John Doe", address:"johndoe@domain.com"}
    end tell

    tell content of theMessage
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment} at after last paragraph
    end tell

end tell
```

Comment: There seems to be a similar problem with JXA. The following works fine in High Sierra but the attachment does not appear in Mojave beta10

Comment: var mail = Application( 'com.apple.Mail' );

var message = mail.OutgoingMessage().make();

message.visible = true;
message.toRecipients.push( mail.Recipient( { address: "someone@somewhere.com" } ) );
message.subject = "Test Email";
message.content = "Test Content";

message.attachments.push( mail.Attachment( { fileName: "/Users/username/Desktop/Example.pdf" } ) );

mail.activate();